# Add a numerical suffix to folder names

Tags: unix

I have a main folder containing other folders (1500 folders) named: A, B, C, D, ...I would like to add a numerical suffix to the folders so that the output will be:

> ```
> A_1
> B_2    
> C_3    
> D_4    
> ....
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in Bash with four test folders A B C D in the same path:

```
i=1
u=_
for j in `ls -1`; do mv "$j" "$j$u$i"; let "i=$i+1"; done
```

I tried `"$j_$i"` and `"$j\_$i"`, neither one worked properly, so I just made the `$u` variable.

I'm going to research if `for` keeps an internal variable of the index of `$j` in the list, because if it does that would simplify it.